# Does ShareKit still work - 2015? And if it does, can be implemented in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks, sharekit

ShareKit... Loved it the past!

I can see there's "movements" currently in the GitHub repo, but tutorials, implementation and captures seems pretty old to me. Also the website and videos.

Does it still works?

More importantly...

And if so, can I "translate" all methods implementation from Objective-C to Swift, I doubt it may have the same functioning behind the scenes when called with Swift. Generally speaking, how these 3rd party frameworks behave when dealing with Swift in your experience... ???

Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 1):

ShareKit seems to be re-incarnated here: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit but it's still implemented in Objective-C. Seems to be working fine though.